# Enabling CORS on Google App Engine Flexible environment PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, google-app-engine

0

I am facing issues enabling CORS support for a PHP (laravel) application that is hosted using Google App Engine and the flexible environment.

Every AJAX request using the axios library results in the following error...

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.[something].services/request' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to add:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

The PHP code above indicates that the wildcard character `*` will allow *everybody* to make Ajax requests to your web application.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com');
```

The PHP code above indicates that `example.com` has permission to make cross-domain requests to your web application.

Additionally, I recommend that you take a look at this [PHP Laravel package](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers with Laravel middleware configuration.

Also see:

- [How to handle CORS (or whatever headers) with GAE in flex environment and PHP runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53599018/how-to-handle-cors-or-whatever-headers-with-gae-in-flex-environment-and-php-ru)

Comment: Im try used this PHP Laravel package and add header in index.php but cannot send request ajax.

Comment: Im using https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors in other server linux it's worked. but deloy by GAE flex it's not working

Comment: I used nginx-app.conf but got same issue. can you help me please

Comment: I see, I think it would be nice if you could post a minimal reproducible sample code to see your configuration/how you're making the request and be able to help you further. Where is your other Linux server hosted? also GCP?

Answer (score 0):

```
runtime: php
env: flex
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 4
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 20
runtime_config:
  document_root: public

# Ensure we skip ".env", which is only for local development
skip_files:
  - .env
  - .git
  - /vendor/
  - /node_modules/

env_variables:
  # Put production environment variables here.
  APP_LOG: errorlog
  APP_KEY: [REDACTED]
  APP_NAME: MyApp
  APP_ENV: production
  APP_DEBUG: false
  APP_URL: https://example.com
  CUSTOM_CSS: example.css
  FRONTEND_URL: https://web.example.com

  LOG_CHANNEL: stackdriver
  LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL: https://hooks.slack.com/services/T011E768GNR/B011E7A307P/CGK4zZwTG1tieLwZ1uTx77

  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_HOST: 127.0.0.1
  DB_PORT: 3306
  DB_DATABASE: dbname
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: [REDACTED]
  DB_SOCKET: "[REDACTED]"
```

This is a part of app.yml

[This is a part of composer.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh1zU.png)

```
protected $middleware = [
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\GaeProxyIp::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\GaeSetHstsHeader::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
    ];
```

Use Fruitcke\Cors

and cors config im using default

```
'paths' => ['api/*'],

    /*
    * Matches the request method. `['*']` allows all methods.
    */
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Matches the request origin. `['*']` allows all origins. Wildcards can be used, eg `*.mydomain.com`
     */
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    /*
     * Patterns that can be used with `preg_match` to match the origin.
     */
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    /*
     * Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header. `['*']` allows all headers.
     */
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
```

Thanks for your support

Comment: Does your App Engine path endpoint starts with `api/` as defined in your code? Have you tried adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header within your application's code? Also see the following [GitHub issue](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/481#issuecomment-701029359). If that does not work, please let me know if moving `\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,` to the top of the list in `$middleware` makes any difference and make sure the steps, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63913814/7725879).